# Handling multiple IdPs in wso2

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

How to achieve below Scenario:

I have multiple IDP such as APM, Predix, etc. Every IDP has its own user management such as a create user, groups, etc.

tenant 1 - APM

tenant 2 - Predix

Is there any configuration in WSO2 base on tenant dependant they will be giving a response such as Tenant 1 in request automatically wso2 connect to APM and giving endpoint information?

Answer (score 0):

Doc - [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfRD2.png), guides the steps to configure federated identity provider to WSO2 IS. You can create different service providers and select the required IdP for each service provider. Steps to configure federated IdP to a service provider can be found in [2], under section "Click here for details on how to configure local and outbound authentication"

Edit: Identity Provider can be created in WSO2 IS to represent the external IdP. We can create service providers (based on the requirement, it could be created in relevant tenants) select federated authentication as "Authentication Type" and select the relevant IdP from drop down menu.Refer the image below:

[image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfRD2.png) https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Configuring+Federated+Authentication
[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Adding+and+Configuring+a+Service+Provider

Comment: Please add an actual solution instead of links to documents that may contain a solution. The answer on SO should contain the actual solution.